# Custom Metrics against a VM in Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am getting authorization error on 'Microsoft.Insights/Metrics/write'

I have a virtual machine resource and a service principle that has contributor role. I am trying to emit metrics against a virtual machine resource. Following the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-store-custom-rest-api

But I am getting this error:

{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"The Azure AD object '0f6a81eb-8950-43eb-989a-f715fb84e4e2' does not have permissions to perform action 'Microsoft.Insights/Metrics/write' over scope '/subscriptions/ba0583bb-4130-4d7b-bfe4-0c7597857323/resourceGroups/sample-PM-LA-resourceGrp/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sample-PM-virtualMachine'. "}}

Here is what I am doing:

```
curl -X POST https://westus2.monitoring.azure.com/subscriptions/ba0583bb-4130-4d7b-bfe4-0c7597857323/resourceGroups/sample-PM-LA-resourceGrp/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sample-PM-virtualMachine/metrics -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <auth-code>" -d @custommetric.json
```

and the error I get:

```
{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"The Azure AD object '0f6a81eb-8950-43eb-989a-f715fb84e4e2' does not have permissions to perform action 'Microsoft.Insights/Metrics/write' over scope '/subscriptions/ba0583bb-4130-4d7b-bfe4-0c7597857323/resourceGroups/sample-PM-LA-resourceGrp/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sample-PM-virtualMachine'. "}}
```

Does any one know why this happens? I have the required permissions and the service principle has also been given the permission.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you mention that Service Principal created has `Contributor` role.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-store-custom-rest-api#create-and-authorize-a-service-principal-to-emit-metrics) specifically calls for `Monitoring Metrics Publisher` role for the service principal.

[image]

Additionaly, I see this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20651) very similar to your issue, where even the `Owner` role for resource doesn't carry this specific permission, so it might not be very intuitive.

So try adding `Monitoring Metrics Publisher` role for Service Principal

Comment: ok now it no longer complains about authorization, however I can't see the metric on Monitor>Metrics page, where the documents asks to check
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-store-custom-rest-api#view-your-metrics

Comment: Ok makes sense.. that confirms Monitoring Metrics Publisher role was required. Now when you go to Metrics page and select correct subscription and resource.. does correct namespace show up in the namespaces dropdown before the metric?

Comment: That actually took a long time to appear on the Metrics end. I guess the first new metrics takes time to appear but subsequent updates appear quickly.

Comment: ok got it @SugethaChandhrasekar. So are you able to see your custom metrics now and it's working after the initial lag?